# An issue when trying to launch and deploy Jetty

Tags: java, jetty

I have an issue whenever I am trying to deploy Jetty on a specific machine (works with others), the machine is a non-English Windows machine.

> [2013-02-15 04:14:05.894] [ERROR] Thread-39
>   System.err
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create tmp dir in
>   C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\ for
>   context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/spdy,null},C:\Program
>   Files\server\work\tmp\my-app\webapps\spdy.war
>
> [2013-02-15 04:14:05.894] [ERROR] Thread-39
>   System.err
>   java.io.IOException: Žw’è‚³‚ê‚½ƒpƒX‚ªŒ©‚Â‚©‚è‚Ü‚¹‚ñB

I tried to see if this is an issue related to admin rights but it is not, I am launching the process with admin rights.

Any suggestions are really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: "non-English Windows machine" means what exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Was able to find the issue out. Jetty does not create the TEMP folder if it doesn't exist so you have to check yourself and create the temp folder if it is not there.

In this instance, it ended up being that:
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\ does not exist although C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\ does and TEMP=C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\

Creating "Temp" directory in C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\ solved the issue!

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty old post, but recently I had just the same problem, so I want to share my experience too.

Parts of the code causing the problem can be found here:
http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/xref/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebInfConfiguration.html#225, `resolveTempDirectory (WebAppContext context)` method (check last lines of the method, third case explained in the comments). So, another workaround for the problem can be also changing default `java.io.tmpdir` folder to point to an existing one.

I have already checked on some systems and `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp` folder doesn't exist on Windows: 7, 2008, 2012.